# Dockerfile is throwing an DNS lookup error while updating packages

Tags: docker, dns, alpine-linux, docker-daemon

While I'm trying to build a new image from a Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

USER root

ENV JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION 8.151.12-r0

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache openjdk8="$JAVA_ALPINE_VERSION" curl
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && rm /usr/bin/java

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin


WORKDIR /tmp

CMD ["sh"]
```

I'm getting the error:

ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: DNS lookup error
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: No such file or directory

The strange thing is:
I have internet access from the machine (linux). I can CURL or ping the outside.
I have built an image to test the internet access inside the container:

- docker run --rm filipegalo/alpine-bash bash -c 'curl -I [http://google.pt/'](http://google.pt/%27)

And I'm able to reach the outside.

Only while I'm trying to update the packages is where I'm getting the error.

Did anyone face the same issue?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe 3.14 has 8.151.12-r0 to begin with, see [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=openjdk8&branch=v3.14)

Comment: I assume `docker run --rm -it alpine:latest nslookup dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org` also doesn't resolve?

Comment: Hello @jabbson, yes `** server can't find dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org: NXDOMAIN `

Comment: But while I run docker run --rm filipegalo/alpine-bash bash -c 'http_proxy=http://xxxx:xxxx curl -I http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org' I'm getting an 200.

Also while running the RUN apk update && apk upgrade with proxy also I'm not able to resolve the DNS.

Comment: docker run --rm filipegalo/alpine-bash bash -c 'http_proxy=http://xxxx:xxxx curl -I https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org

docker run --rm filipegalo/alpine-bash bash -c 'http_proxy=http://xxxx:xxxx curl -I http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org'
 0HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: I figured out the problem I was using an http proxy while reaching https. 
Changing http_proxy to https_proxy solved.